# Cómo validar un CUIT por REGEX

Tags: angular, typescript, regex

La expresión regular que sirve para validar CUITs argentinos es la siguiente:

```
/^([0-9]{11}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1})$/g
```

Esa sólo verifica cantidad de caracteres, se puede complicar más obviamente, por ej:

```
/^(20|23|27|30|33)([0-9]{9}|-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1})$/g
```

Validando también el inicio en 20, 23, 27, 30, 33. Acá va un ejemplo de como usarlo en TypeScript:

```
isCuitValid(cuit: string): boolean {
    const regexCuit = /^(20|23|27|30|33)([0-9]{9}|-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1})$/g;
    return regexCuit.test(cuit);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido alejandro juarez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Una curiosidad: ¿Por que en vez de validar el patrón de entrada, no validas directamente la CUIT usando el digito verificador?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho sinceramente no se me había ocurrido, de hecho es más precisa la que propones

Comment: Aquí hay una rutina que tal vez pueda servirte: https://gist.github.com/neiker/874c197cd0cbb06efb328f3cbc6753b3

Comment: Desde junio de 2021 las dos primeras cifras del [CUIL y el CUIT no distinguen género](https://www.iprofesional.com/legales/341033-cuit-y-cuil-los-2-s-digitos-no-se-relacionaran-al-genero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejo un ejercicio completo. El CUIT debería tomarlo de la matriz de argumentos de entrada pero, por simplificar, lo añadí manualmente. Cambia el valor en la línea `result = ValidamosCuit("30-68537634-9");` para probar con otros.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CuitValidation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool result;
            result = ValidamosCuit("30-68537634-9");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Validación Final: {0}", result));
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static bool ValidamosCuit(string cuit)
        {
            string cuitlimpio;
            bool isTmpValid = ValidaCuitRegex(cuit, out cuitlimpio);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Validación Regex: {0}", isTmpValid));
            if (isTmpValid)
                isTmpValid = ValidaCuitDCr(cuitlimpio);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Validación Dígito Control: {0}", isTmpValid));
            return isTmpValid;
        }

        private static bool ValidaCuitRegex(string cuit, out string cuitlimpio)
        {
            const string RegexPatternToExtractNumbers = @"\d+";
            const string RegexPatternCuit = @"^(20|2[3-7]|30|3[3-4])(\d{8})(\d)$";
            
            // limpiamos el cuit. Dejamos sólo números
            cuitlimpio = string.Empty;
            Regex rx = new Regex(RegexPatternToExtractNumbers, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var matches = rx.Matches(cuit);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                cuitlimpio = string.Concat(cuitlimpio, match.Value);
            }

            // Analizamos el cuit limpio
            rx = new Regex(RegexPatternCuit, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            return (rx.Match(cuitlimpio).Success);
        }

        private static bool ValidaCuitDCr(string cuit)
        {
            const string verificacion = "5432765432";

            int dc = -1; //Cualquier valor no válido (para asegurar)
            int sumador = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < verificacion.Length; i++)
            {
                sumador += (int.Parse(cuit.Substring(i, 1))) * (int.Parse(verificacion.Substring(i, 1)));
            }

            // obtenemos el resto
            int resto = sumador % 11;
            // Lo restamos a 11
            int preResult = 11 - resto;
            switch (preResult)
            {
                // si el ressultado de preResult es == 11. El valor es 0
                case 11:
                    dc = 0;
                    break;
                // si preResult es igual a 10. El valor es 9
                case 10:
                    dc = 9;
                    break;
                // en todos los demas casos es el preResult
                default:
                    dc = preResult;
                    break;
            }
            return (dc == (int.Parse(cuit.Substring(10, 1))));
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hace:

1. Limpia el CUIT, dejando sólo números.
2. Valida que el primer bloque se corresponda con los valores posibles (según https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_%C3%9Anica_de_Identificaci%C3%B3n_Tributaria)
3. Valida que el último bloque (dígito de control) sea el correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Se actualizo si no me equivoco.

Tipos:
20, 23, 24 y 27 para Personas Físicas
30, 33 y 34 para Empresas.

Tambien contiene funciones para cada lenguaje por un requicito que desconozco

"Procedimiento para obtener el dígito verificador"
"...En el siguiente ejemplo se toma como CUIT el número ##-12345678-X, donde ## es el tipo, 12345678 es el número de DNI o número de sociedad y X es el dígito verificador.
..."

[wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_%C3%9Anica_de_Identificaci%C3%B3n_Tributaria#:%7E:text=Consta%20de%20un%20total%20de,y%20finalmente%20un%20d%C3%ADgito%20verificador.)

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar la librería https://github.com/pixelario/CUIT

```
Install-Package Pixelario.CUIT -Version 0.10.3
```

Instancias tipos de datos CUIT que tienen su método IsValid()

Ejemplo:

```
var cuit = CUIT.Parse(
    cuit: this.txtNumerodoc.Text);

if(cuit.IsValid())
{
   this.lbValidacion.Text="Es un digito valido";
}
else 
{
    this.lbValidaction.Text="Es un digito invalido";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

En Argentina, el CUIT (Clave Única de Identificación Tributaria) tiene un formato estándar de 11 dígitos. Este formato incluye el número de documento de la persona o entidad, un número de entidad y un dígito verificador. La distribución de los dígitos puede variar dependiendo de si se trata de una persona física o jurídica.

- **Para personas físicas:** 2 dígitos (número de documento) + 8 dígitos (número de entidad) + 1 dígito verificador = 11 dígitos en total.
- **Para personas jurídicas:** 5 o 6 dígitos (número de documento) + 3 dígitos (número de entidad) + 1 dígito verificador = 11 dígitos en total.

En resumen, el CUIT siempre tiene un total de 11 dígitos, independientemente de si es para una persona física o jurídica. No hay un número mínimo o máximo de dígitos diferentes de 11 en un CUIT válido en Argentina.

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular en JavaScript para validar un CUIT argentino:

```js
const regexCUIT = /^\d{2}-\d{8}-\d{1}$/;
```

Esta expresión regular asume que el CUIT tiene el formato estándar de dos dígitos, seguidos por un guion, ocho dígitos, otro guion y finalmente un dígito. Puedes usar esta expresión regular en funciones de validación para asegurarte de que un CUIT dado cumpla con el formato esperado. Por ejemplo:

```js
function validarCUIT(cuit) {
  const regexCUIT = /^\d{2}-\d{8}-\d{1}$/;
  return regexCUIT.test(cuit);
}

// Ejemplo de uso
const cuitValido = "12-34567890-1";
const cuitInvalido = "123-4567890-1";

console.log(validarCUIT(cuitValido));   // Devolverá true
console.log(validarCUIT(cuitInvalido)); // Devolverá false
```

Recuerda que esta expresión regular solo verifica el formato del CUIT, no su validez real en términos de asignación por parte de la AFIP. Puede ser útil como una primera capa de validación, pero es posible que también desees realizar otras verificaciones según tus necesidades específicas.

Comment: Hmmmm... Solo por las dudas: [La IA generativa (ej.: ChatGPT) está prohibida en el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/) y [¿Por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable?](/help/gpt-policy).